# CKEditor insert html duplicates

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Here's my code

```
    CKEDITOR.rbcPluginTools.addCustomPlugins('custom_author_signature', [
    {
        name: "author_signature",
        title: "Подпись автора",
        tooltip: "Добавить подпись автора",
        icon: 'author_signature',
        hidpi: true,
        toolbar: "media,9",
        exec: function (plugin, editor) {
            selection = editor.getSelection();
            if(selection.getSelectedText()) {
                editor.insertHtml(`<div class="back_container author_signature">${editor.getSelection().document.getBody().getHtml()}</div>`);
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

'back_container' is for background-color. Looks like it duplicates divs for some weird reason, cause after 2 executions it makes 3 back colors instead of two.
Expected behavior:

1. select text -> press plugin button -> 1 background container
2. select text inside this background container -> press plugin button -> 2 background containers (not 3!)

Comment: Мне кажеться кавычки для оберывания у тебя не такие как надо.

Comment: такие, я проверял. Проблема еще и в том, что этот код даже близко неправильный. Он просто делает insertHtml, то есть вставляет Html а не "обертывает". Я особо с js не дружу, поэтому решил спросить тк это вроде что-то легкое, дольше разбираться буду.

Comment: Разве не легче просто в том месте где выводиться контент просто обернуть его. Или тебе надо сам контент обернуть в стили и положить в БД их ? Попробуй поиск ckeditor wrap content in div

Comment: да я уже погуглил и почти справился. Хотя нашел много похожего неотвеченного так что мб мой вопрос полезен. Сейчас осталась одна проблема. Когда я обертываю в див то, что я уже обернул в див, у меня на заднем плане появляются 3 прямоугольника вместо двух.

Comment: я понял почему, видимо скоро сам отвечу на свой вопрос)